# Why does ProjectionFactory convert nulls to empty Optionals?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Recently I updated my project from Spring Boot 2.1.0 to Spring Boot 2.5.6. Since then I see differences in JSON serialization.

To distinguish between cases (a) *any value*, (b) *explicit null*, and (c) *no value* I use `java.util.Optional` and Jackson's `@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)` annotation. Furthermore I use Spring Data JPA's projection pattern to define the JSON format as follows:

```
public interface MyProjection {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    Optional<String> getMyAttribute();
}
```

This worked perfect with Spring Boot 2.1.0.

| Field value | Rendered JSON |
| --- | --- |
| `Optional.of("something")` | `{ "myAttribute": "something" }` |
| `Optional.empty()` | `{ "myAttribute": null }` |
| `null` | `{}` |

As of now (after my update to Spring Boot 2.5.6) `null` is rendered like `Optional.empty()`:

| Field value | Rendered JSON |
| --- | --- |
| `Optional.of("something")` | `{ "myAttribute": "something" }` |
| `Optional.empty()` | `{ "myAttribute": null }` |
| `null` | `{ "myAttribute": null }` |

My first assumption was that Jackson's `NON_NULL` no longer works correctly with `Optional`. But that was not the case. As @Pedro said, it works correctly. After some investigation I found out that Spring's `ProjectionFactory` seems to handle `null` values different. It converts `null` to `Optional.empty()`, while it didn't do that formerly.

I'd like the old behavior back. Does anyone know how to prevent Spring from converting nulls to empty Optionals and instead keep it nulls? Is there a new default configuration? I didn't find any.

Comment: The documentation for `NON_NULL` hasn't changed between the versions, so I think you should report this to their developers.

Comment: Is `MyProjection` an interface ? For 2.12.2 it seems all work fine.

Comment: I could not reproduce this with that version of Jackson. Could you share a simple code snippet that demonstrates the issue at hand?

Comment: Thanks to @dariosicily for making me think about my question. After further investigation, I found the actual problem. See my updated question.

Comment: Thanks to @Pedro for making me think about my question. After further investigation, I found the actual problem. See my updated question.

Comment: so your problem is with ProjectionFactory, not Jackson, is that right?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, it isn't a Jackson issue anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I can no longer use `java.util.Optional` for my purposes. Spring developers extended [`ProjectingMethodInterceptor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/projection/ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java) to [convert `null` values into the *empty* representation of the used wrapper type](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/repository-projections.adoc#nullable-wrappers) (that is `Optional.empty()` in my case).

That applies to other wrapper types as well:

- `com.google.common.base.Optional`
- `scala.Option`
- `io.vavr.control.Option`

Answer (score 0):

After a few time of searching, i found the interested test case.

Here is the excerpt of test case with optional in jackson projects:

```
public void testConfigAbsentsAsNullsTrue() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module().configureAbsentsAsNulls(true));

        OptionalData data = new OptionalData();
        String value = mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).writeValueAsString(data);
        assertEquals("{}", value);
    }

    public void testConfigAbsentsAsNullsFalse() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module().configureAbsentsAsNulls(false));

        OptionalData data = new OptionalData();
        String value = mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).writeValueAsString(data);
        assertEquals("{\"myString\":null}", value);
    }

    class OptionalData {
        public Optional<String> myString = Optional.empty();
    }
```

Unit test Optional Link:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/TestConfigureAbsentsAsNulls.java

And there is a note configureAbsentsAsNulls.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.java

```
For compatibility with older versions
     * of other "optional" values (like Guava optionals), it can be set to 'true'. The
     * default is `false` for backwards compatibility. 
public Jdk8Module configureAbsentsAsNulls(boolean state) {
    _cfgHandleAbsentAsNull = state;
    return this;
}
```

So you just need to set configureAbsentsAsNulls(true) to roll back your previous state.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation that helped me to find the real problem. See my updated question.

Comment: Glad when it help.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the  `@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)` to solve the problem and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

There is a three-way to ignore the null field at 1). Field level 2). Class level 3). Globally

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private String userName;

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
 public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
 private String title;
 private String author;
 private int price;

  public Book(String title, String author, int price) {
   this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
   }
  }


// let's create a book with author as null 
 Book book = new Book(null, null, 42);  
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
 // configure ObjectMapper to exclude null fields whiel serializing 
 mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);   
 String json =mapper.writeValueAsString(cleanCode); 
 System.out.println(json);
```